# Python convert string to existing dict name to add key value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating an automated script that preprocesses Landsat satellite imagery.  The script parses through a metadata text file looking for correction coefficients.  There are already 6 existing dictionaries (similar to below) that contain some of the coefficients needed to process the imagery, depending on the satellite and sensor that collected the image:

```
TM5 = {'ESUN1':1983,'ESUN2':1796,'ESUN3':1536} #Landsat5 Thematic Mapper
ETM7 = {'ESUN1':1997,'ESUN2':1812,'ESUN3':1533} #Landsat7 Enhanced Thematic Mapper
```

The dictionary name corresponds to the satellite and sensor.  As the script parses through the .txt, these variables are created:

```
sat = 'ETM7' # sat/sensor, also the name of a dict
key = 'LMIN1' 
val = -1.520
```

Based on the `sat` variable, I want to be able to add a new key/val pair to the correct dictionary (in this case, the `ETM7` dictionary).  However when I do this

```
sat[key] = val
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    sat[key] = val
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I understand what the error means, but I don't know how say pythonically, this string variable is actually the name of an existing dictionary, so add this key/val pair without having to completely recreate/overwrite the existing dictionary.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: A string is a string, even if the characters it contains are also the name of a variable. That is why strings have quotes around them and variable names don't.

Comment: You need to call the dictionary name directly and not through a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to refer to a dictionary using a string containing its name, use `eval(sat)[key]` instead of `sat[key]`.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to recommend using `eval` on arbitrary input when there are slightly different but safer options.

Answer (score 0):

On option is **Create mapping** record of existing dictionaries.

**Limitation**: Can not able to create new dictionary in mapping.

Demo:

```
TM5 = {'ESUN1':1983,'ESUN2':1796,'ESUN3':1536} 
ETM7 = {'ESUN1':1997,'ESUN2':1812,'ESUN3':1533}

manpping = {"ETM7":ETM7, "TM5":TM5}

sat = 'ETM7'
key = 'LMIN1' 
val = -1.520

if sat in manpping:
    manpping[sat][key] = val

print "ETM7:", ETM7
```

Output:

```
$ python task4.py 
ETM7: {'ESUN2': 1812, 'ESUN3': 1533, 'ESUN1': 1997, 'LMIN1': -1.52}
```

---

Create new dictionary in mapping for new key information.

Demo:

```
import pprint

TM5 = {'ESUN1':1983,'ESUN2':1796,'ESUN3':1536} 
ETM7 = {'ESUN1':1997,'ESUN2':1812,'ESUN3':1533}

manpping = {"ETM7":ETM7, "TM5":TM5}

sat = 'ETM7'
key = 'LMIN1' 
val = -1.520

if not sat in manpping:
    manpping[sat] = {}

manpping[sat][key] = val

print "mmaping value:"
pprint.pprint(manpping)
print "ETM7:"
pprint.pprint(ETM7)

#- No maaping present.
print "\nNo maaping present."
sat = 'ATM5'
key = 'ATM' 
val = 1.520

if not sat in manpping:
    manpping[sat] = {}

manpping[sat][key] = val

print "mmaping value:"
pprint.pprint(manpping)
```

Output:

```
mmaping value:
{'ETM7': {'ESUN1': 1997, 'ESUN2': 1812, 'ESUN3': 1533, 'LMIN1': -1.52},
 'TM5': {'ESUN1': 1983, 'ESUN2': 1796, 'ESUN3': 1536}}
ETM7:
{'ESUN1': 1997, 'ESUN2': 1812, 'ESUN3': 1533, 'LMIN1': -1.52}

No maaping present.
mmaping value:
{'ATM5': {'ATM': 1.52},
 'ETM7': {'ESUN1': 1997, 'ESUN2': 1812, 'ESUN3': 1533, 'LMIN1': -1.52},
 'TM5': {'ESUN1': 1983, 'ESUN2': 1796, 'ESUN3': 1536}}
```

---

`eval()` will work.

Demo:

```
TM5 = {'ESUN1':1983,'ESUN2':1796,'ESUN3':1536} 
ETM7 = {'ESUN1':1997,'ESUN2':1812,'ESUN3':1533}

sat = 'ETM7'
key = 'LMIN1' 
val = -1.520
try:
    tmp = eval(sat)
    tmp[key] = val
    print "Values:", tmp
except NameError:
    print "No dictionary variable present with name %s"%(sat)


print "-"*10
sat = 'STI7'
key = 'STIN1' 
val = -1.520
try:
    tmp = eval(sat)
    tmp[key] = [val]
    print "Values:", tmp
except NameError:
    print "No dictionary variable present with name %s"%(sat)
```

Output:

```
$ python task4.py 
Values: {'ESUN2': 1812, 'ESUN3': 1533, 'ESUN1': 1997, 'LMIN1': -1.52}
----------
No dictionary variable present with name STI7
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use a single data structure, and use the `sat` and `key` as a tuple to key the structure. Doesn't require anything fancy.

```
data = {}

def set_sat_val(sat, key, val):
   data[(sat, key)] = val


def get_sat_val(sat, key):
  return data[(sat, key)]

set_sat_val('ETM7', 'LMIN1', -1.520)

get_sat_val('ETM7', 'LMIN1')
>>> -1.52

set_sat_val('ETM7', 'LMIN2', -1.620)
set_sat_val('ETM7', 'LMIN3', -1.720)

get_sat_val('ETM7', 'LMIN2')
>>> -1.62

get_sat_val('ETM7', 'LMIN3')
>>> -1.72
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionaries are global variables, you can do:

`globals()[sat]`

globals is a function that returns a dictionary which contains global variables.